RBAC on a Kusto cluster for functions
Context :  Admin for a Kusto cluster and need to share kusto functions with report development team, without giving access to any underlying tables to query directly.
Question : Is it possible to grant read only access to kusto functions to end users like report development team, so that they cannot run their own queries on the underlying tables? The functions have been written to work in an efficient way with right joins and hints and the functions are updated frequently to add new field requests from end user/report development team.
I see there is only an admin role available for functions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kusto/management/manage-function-security-roles?view=microsoft-fabric
Was unable to figure out if there is a combination of other access roles we could use to achieve this?
